# Worst fit algorithm Java

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm working on a worst fit algorithm in Java using a dynamic array , I'm trying to add and delete blocks/processes , the addition is working perfectly fine but when I want to delete a block , I'm not really sure if it's deleting the blocks well or no , I had an error message that said : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 3 out of bounds for length 3.I fixed the code and it's working , could someone please tell me if i'm doing it corrct or no

**Here's the CODE :**

```
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class GFG {
    // Method to allocate memory to blocks as per worst fit
    // algorithm
    static int[] worstFit(int[] blockSize, int[] processSize) {
        // Stores block id of the block allocated to a
        // process
        int m = blockSize.length;
        int n = processSize.length;
        int[] allocation = new int[n];

        // Initially no block is assigned to any process
        Arrays.fill(allocation, -1);

        // pick each process and find suitable blocks
        // according to its size ad assign to it
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            // Find the best fit block for current process
            int wstIdx = -1;
            for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
                if (blockSize[j] >= processSize[i]) {
                    if (wstIdx == -1)
                        wstIdx = j;
                    else if (blockSize[wstIdx] < blockSize[j])
                        wstIdx = j;
                }
            }

            // If we could find a block for current process
            if (wstIdx != -1) {
                // allocate block j to p[i] process
                allocation[i] = wstIdx;

                // Reduce available memory in this block.
                blockSize[wstIdx] -= processSize[i];
            }
        }

        System.out.println("\nProcess No.\tProcess Size\tBlock no.");
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.print("   " + (i + 1) + "\t\t" + processSize[i] + "\t\t");
            if (allocation[i] != -1)
                System.out.print(allocation[i] + 1);
            else
                System.out.print("Not Allocated");
            System.out.println();
        }
        return allocation;
    }

    static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Driver Method
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] blockSize = addBlocks();
        int[] processSize = addProcess();

        int[] allocation = worstFit(blockSize, processSize);


       int[] temp =  deleteBlock(blockSize);
        worstFit(temp, processSize);
    }

    private static int[] addBlocks() {
        int[] temp = null;
        System.out.print("Enter number of blocks : ");
        int len = in.nextInt();
        temp = new int[len];
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            System.out.printf("Enter block[%s] size: ", i);
            temp[i] = in.nextInt();
        }
        return temp;
    }

    private static int[] deleteBlock(int[] blocks) {
        int c = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < blocks.length; i++) {
            System.out.printf("Block id %s blockSize= %s%n", i, blocks[i]);
        }
        System.out.println("Enter block id to delete");
        int id = in.nextInt();

        int[] temp = new int[blocks.length - 1];
        if (id == blocks.length) {
            for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
                temp[i] = blocks[i];
            }
        }
            else if(id<blocks.length)
            for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++){
                if(i!=id){
                temp[c] = blocks[i];
                c++;
                }
        }
        return temp;
    }

    private static int[] addProcess() {
        int[] temp;
        System.out.print("Enter number of Process : ");
        int len = in.nextInt();

        temp = new int[len];
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            System.out.printf("Enter Process[%s] size:  ", i);
            temp[i] = in.nextInt();
        }
        return temp;
    }

    private static void deleteProcess() {
    }

 }
```

Comment: If the code is working, this question should go to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/